# How to connect Corona SDK app to Sails.js server

Tags: node.js, lua, coronasdk, sails.js

I have my Corona application which connects to a server through sockets

```
local socket = require("socket");
local connect, error = socket.connect('127.0.0.1', 1337);

if (connect == nil) then
    print('Connection error: ' .. error);
    return false;
end

print('Connected');
```

My server on Node.js

```
var net     = require('net'),
    server  = net.createServer()
;

server.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('New client: ' + socket.remoteAddress + ':' + socket.remotePort);
});

server.listen(1337);
```

When I run the application on the server console prompt appears `New client: 127.0.0.1:PORT`.

Now I'm trying to connect to my server on Sails.js but nothing happens. When I go to 127.0.0.1:1337 by browser server returned `info: handshake authorized SOCKET_ID`, but when I try to connect by the app nothing's happen.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you getting either of the prints showing up in your device's console log?

Comment: @RobMiracle yes, the console device shows 'Connected'.

Comment: Well the "Connected" message is going to print regardless of a successful connection.  What happens if you try to do a:  

telnet 127.0.0.1 1337

??

Comment: @RobMiracle nothing happens. I think in this case, the problem in the socket.io protocol. I use the native socket connection in my Corona app. But Sails.js are working with socket.io, which has its own protocol. Maybe I'm wrong.